# How to prevent a responsive Website from opening in a cordova or webView based container app?

Tags: cordova, security, web, mobile

Ideally this should be helpful in mitigating the risks from fake apps.

What technical measures can we take to prevent a website from opening in a content based mobile application? This way requests from unauthorised sources can be blocked.